# Macbook Pro - bottom part of the screen partly mirrors the top

Tags: screen

[image: picture]

Making the computer sleep will remove this symptom for a while.

Tried disabling hardware acceleration (GPU) via setting or gSwitch, resetting SMC and PRAM/NVRAM, and rebooting. Apple diagnostics has not been identifying any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - unless you’re sure it’s software, I would get it to Apple Service for a look. One method to perform a quick check is boot to recovery - hold option and R. If the firmware screen is broken, you know it’s GPU / CPU.

If the firmware screen is perfect, you would want to back up and then perform an erase install. It’s possible hardware failure could happen only when all graphic drivers are fully loaded and optimized / accelerated.

Comment: Yes I think a visit to Apple Service would be the normal solution. However, this is the 2016 model and my AppleCare had expired. I am wondering if it is possible to have a stopgap solution. I do not mind periodically running script that restarts my display without requiring my computer to sleep (which removes the symptoms for a while).

Comment: I’ll keep your situation in mind in case another option or idea strikes. @HKTong